# When bar.constructor === Object is true?

Tags: javascript

On [totpal](https://www.toptal.com/javascript/interview-questions)

Below question is present.

> What is a potential pitfall with using typeof bar === "object" to
>   determine if bar is an object? How can this pitfall be avoided?

Among its answers below statement is present

```
However, there’s one other alternative that returns false for nulls,
arrays, and functions, but true for objects:

console.log((bar !== null) && (bar.constructor === Object));
```

But when I try my code

```
var myObj = 
    {
        name: "blah"
    }

var bar =3;

console.log(typeof bar.constructor)
console.log(typeof myObj.constructor)
```

it gives output as `function`  for both `console.log`

My question is what type of objects will have `(bar.constructor === Object)` as `true`?

Comment: You've mixed up two things here. `bar.constructor === Object` is `true`, because `constructor` it's in fact Object `function`, that's why its `typeof` is function. AFAIK, constructor is always some function.

Comment: @erhesto: just a few minute back I noticed it. My question is incorrect. Can't delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"My question is what type of objects will have `(bar.constructor === Object)` as `true`?"*

Generally, objects that inherit *directly* from `Object.prototype` instead of some intermediate constructor's `.prototype` or `null`.

Note that objects that do inherit directly from `Object.prototype` but shadow the `.constructor` property with its own value that doesn't point to `Object` will of course result in a `false` result of an equality comparison.

```js
var o = {};
console.log(o.constructor === Object); // true
o.constructor = "foo";
console.log(o.constructor === Object); // false
```

Also, objects that do not inherit directly from `Object.prototype`, but rather from some other constructor that has a `.prototype` *without* a `.constructor` property will give a `true` result.

```js
function Ctor() {}
var o = new Ctor();
console.log(o.constructor === Object); // false
delete Ctor.prototype.constructor;
console.log(o.constructor === Object); // true
```